# C++ Modifying struct passed to function as a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct _wfs_result
{
    REQUESTID       RequestID;
    HSERVICE        hService;
    SYSTEMTIME      tsTimestamp;
    HRESULT         hResult;
    union {
        DWORD       dwCommandCode;
        DWORD       dwEventID;
    } u;
    LPVOID          lpBuffer;
} WFSRESULT, * LPWFSRESULT;
```

A pointer to the struct is passed to this function:

```
int DLL_EXPORT WFSGetInfo ( HSERVICE hService, DWORD dwCategory, LPVOID
lpQueryDetails, DWORD dwTimeOut, LPWFSRESULT * lppResult)
```

However, when I try to modify the struct inside the function, it won't let me (doesn't compile)
This is how I tried to access it inside the function:

```
lppResult->RequestID = 123;
or
(*lppResult).RequestID = 123;
```

The second one compiles, but I get access violation in the debugger.
Any thoughts?

EDIT:
This is the error I get in Codeblocks:

```
'RequestID' in 'lppResult', which is of non-class type '_wfs_result**'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Are we to guess at the diagnostics you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LPWFSRESULT * lppResult` is a pointer to a pointer to a structure. Usually it means that it is an *output* paramter. You pass a pointer to a variable where the result should be stored.

The type of the variable is `WFSRESULT*`, not `WFSRESULT`. It means that the function is expected to allocate a memory for `WFSRESULT` and put a pointer to `WFSRESULT` structure into the output variable.

Your problem is that you assume that `*lppResult` contains valid pointer while actually it contains garbage.

You can avoid creating new object on a heap by pointer dereferencing

```
int DLL_EXPORT WFSGetInfo ( HSERVICE hService, DWORD dwCategory, LPVOID lpQueryDetails, DWORD dwTimeOut, WFSRESULT & lppResult);
```

Then you can pass and modify the output parameter without any problems.

Comment: So basically I need to create the structure myself inside the function and store the pointer to the structure at the address of the passed pointer?

Comment: Yes. But I suggest to derefer the pointer and to pass just a pointer to the structure. The memory for the structure in this case it allocated by the caller.

Comment: I am sorry I can't make it work, can you please describe what you mean in a few lines of code?

Answer (score 2):

The second one didn't compile with this error with gcc 4.8.2 on Wandbox:

> error: request for member 'RequestID' in '* lppResult', which is of pointer type 'LPWFSRESULT {aka _wfs_result*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?

As `WFSRESULT` is type `WFSRESULT**`, try this: `(*lppResult)->RequestID = 123;`

Comment: This one throws access violation in the debugger.

Comment: Segmentation Fault didn't occur in [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/g8bm9fz28KCawdmx). Check your memory allocation or pointer getting code.

Comment: @msbir If you'd posted a complete, compilable example it would be easier for others to reproduce your problems.

Comment: @AlanStokes thanks for reaching out, unfortunately I only have access to the code I posted, I am trying to simulate a DLL so the rest of the action happens in the debugger as I am reversing the code of the main application.

Answer (score 2):

You have a pointer to a pointer, so you need to dereference it twice. `(*lppResult)->RequestID` would work.

However, on Windows a signature of this sort usually means that the function being called is expected to allocate memory and assign it to `lppResult`. In which case you will need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

LppResult is a level 2 pointer, that's why you got access violation. Try derefer it more time.